# Replacing chandelier with new, No ground wire in old chandelier

Tags: electrical, lighting

I am replacing a chandelier with new one, No ground wire in old chandelier and my vaulted ceiling is at least 30 feet high.  Can I just not connect the ground wire and coil it up so it is out of the way at the base of the hanging part of the new chandelier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ground wires are there to prevent a metal chassis from becoming live in a electrical fault.   if the chandelier is out of range of human contact, the ground wire is not necessary (although, legally it may be.). For safety, look at GFCI options- either at the panel, or by taking the power to the switch off a nearby GFCI outlet.  Then, just coil the ground wire up and tuck it away.

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10087/wiring-a-gfci-switch-combo.   see this.