# Change GFCI outlet/switch with regular switch

Tags: wiring, gfci, receptacle

I have 2 switches in my bathroom: a fan (power comes into the fan and it's just a simple black/white to the switch) and a switch/outlet GFCI combo where the switch powers the lights but the outlet always has power (power comes in at the box with separate line to the lights)

It seems very backwards to anyone hitting switches that the small switch is the lights and single large switch is the fan, thus I want to swap them.

First, based on the configuration, is it possible to do a simple swap for the switches? I don't care if the fan would be GFCI protected or not using that switch. However, based on this [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/25814/how-do-i-wire-a-gfci-combination-light-switch-when-power-enters-at-the-light?lq=1) I have a feeling it's not possible? (Apologies if this isn't possible and you'd consider the question a duplicate, I'm being optimistic this situation is different enough I can rewrite it)

If it is possible can anyone point me at a diagram on how I'd wire this up?
If helpful, here's a picture of how it's wired now (power in, lights, fan)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to simply swap the switches.

This is your current wiring (grounds have been removed to make it less confusing).

[image]

There should be no problem with you swapping the switches like so...

[image]

Comment: Who needs _SketchUp_ or _AutoCad_ when there is a scrap of paper, some markers and a camera phone?  Love the quick sketch!!

Answer (score 1):

Cheating your question a little bit

But what about 2 deora switch in one of the 2 gang box

google B000FKDMAU

The light on the top and the fan on the bottom, seems reasonable

And a GFI of your choice in the other space

Comment: Not a bad idea. I'll consider it as a plan B (only because I don't really want to buy new hardware)